# How to set hadoop replication in java client by class org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration?

Tags: java, api, file-upload, replication

I use the java Api as client to upload files ,but it always set the `dfs.replication` to 3,as a result when I use command (hadoop dfsadmin -report) to check the situation,all blocks are under replication factor,because I just have two data nodes to test.

I just want to know how to set hadoop dfs.replication in java client by class `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration` or in another way? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

IF file is already copied to HDFS with 3 blocks replication, you can use setReplication API along with your file src and expected replication count to set replication specific to your file as below:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
fs.setReplication(new Path("hdfs_path:/foldername/filename"), (short)2);
```

setReplication API is described [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html): 
public boolean setReplication(Path src, short replication)

Also if want to copy files with 2 blocks replication factor you can pass replication count directly in your command as below:

```
hadoop fs -D dfs.replication=2 YOUR_COMMANDS
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Java API for the Hadoop FileSystem class](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) you can specify the replication factor for a file when creating the output stream to write a file to the cluster. E.g.

```
create(Path f, short replication)
```

I currently cannot test this locally as I only have a Zookeeper node running here.